# Use jquery accordion with table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Can I somehow make jQuery UI Accordion compatible with a html table? I've tried everything to make columns collapsible.

Right know I've done this

```
$(".col1, .col2").addClass("hidden");

$(".show-hide-col1").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function() {
    $(".col2").addClass("hidden");
    $(".col1").removeClass("hidden");
});

$(".show-hide-col2").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function() {
    $(".col1").addClass("hidden");
    $(".col2").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

but it's just not as smart as jquery accordion.

Comment: Show you `html,css` code to clear more about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table width="50%" border="1px solid red">
    <tr><td class="col1">Col1</td><td class="col2">Col2</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="show-hide-col1">Hide col1</button>
<button class="show-hide-col2">Hide col2</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-hide-col1").click(function() {
        $('.col1').toggle();
    });
    
    $(".show-hide-col2").click(function() {
        $('.col2').toggle();
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/3qbe4coj/3/

**Note:** If you use hide, it only hide the element. But if you use toggle instead, it can be use to show and hide in single button

Comment: Hi Rohan,
I've been trying to do it with `<table>`, but I can't seem to figure out how to group the columns which should be collapsible. I've been looking in the API, and I can't find any options to tell the script which columns should be collapsible, only which elements should be the header

Comment: @Nets test the above, I have made changes.